# Does an answer like this one need work?

Tags: discussion

I was perusing the site and ran across [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/786179/518562) answer:

> You need to boot up a LiveCD/LiveUSB Ubuntu. After the desktop
>   appears, open GParted and delete swap and ext partitions. Apply
>   changes and now Ubuntu is gone.
>
> For how to remove GRUB and repair Windows bootloader, you can look
>   here:
>   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader
>   or
>   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader
>   or
>   [How to fix the MBR for Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326532/how-to-fix-the-mbr-for-windows-7).
>
> It doesn't matter if you have Win 7, 8 or 10. The repair mechanism is
>   the same.

**It needs work, right?** When I look at it, these things stick out at me:

- Vague explanation of deletion process
- Including many links for the second part of the process, but nothing in the answer itself
- It's better to restore the Windows MBR before deleing Ubuntu, so that a Windows recovery disc is not needed

Comment: Yes, it certainly needs work. However, that's a very old question and it's probably best to just close it as a dupe of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533) (I cast the first close vote).

Comment: As always, when you see a bad answer, chance are that the question is the culprit.

Answer (score 6):

In fact that's not an answer, it only contains links and no answer at all, really. See the chart below for identifying answers:

[image]

Or let's just assume I'm the questioner and not very savvy in terms of computer knowledge, I would be lost with that answer, having to pick the information needed on different places, which might even change over time. This most probably would raise more question as answering the one I had.

Always remember asking for help is harder than giving an answer.

Comment: Well, the first part is actually an answer: "You need to boot up a LiveCD/LiveUSB Ubuntu. After the desktop appears, open GParted and delete swap and ext partitions. Apply changes and now Ubuntu is gone."

Comment: But my flag for "Mostly links" was declined!

Comment: @AndroidDev probably because even if you remove all the links, the answer is still giving a (bad, limited etc) answer to the question.

Comment: @AndroidDev That flag was likely refused as you flagged it for a mod (custom reason), those type of flags are for special circumstances only. You should of flagged it as `low quality` so it goes to the review queue and normal users can vote.

Comment: No, it is an answer, like terdon said. Your graphic contradicts you even ;) [here is the post it comes from](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/203389)

Comment: @AndroidDev I declined your flag. Please read the post I linked in my comment above. This IS an answer. It's not amazing, but it is an answer. No moderator action is needed.